# battery service life dropped after switching to ubuntu

Tags: battery

Since i switched from windows to ubuntu, my battery doesn't last more than 20 minutes. Before it took about 4 hours to become empty.. Can anybody help me on that?

$--- TLP 0.8 --------------------------------------------

+++ Configured Settings: /etc/default/tlp
TLP_ENABLE=1
TLP_DEFAULT_MODE=AC
DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_AC=0
DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_BAT=2
MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_AC=15
MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_BAT=60
SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_AC=0
SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_BAT=1
NMI_WATCHDOG=0
ENERGY_PERF_POLICY_ON_AC=performance
ENERGY_PERF_POLICY_ON_BAT=powersave
DISK_DEVICES="sda sdb"
DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_AC="254 254"
DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_BAT="128 128"
SATA_LINKPWR_ON_AC=max_performance
SATA_LINKPWR_ON_BAT=min_power
PCIE_ASPM_ON_AC=performance
PCIE_ASPM_ON_BAT=powersave
RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_AC=high
RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_BAT=low
RADEON_DPM_STATE_ON_AC=performance
RADEON_DPM_STATE_ON_BAT=battery
RADEON_DPM_PERF_LEVEL_ON_AC=auto
RADEON_DPM_PERF_LEVEL_ON_BAT=auto
WIFI_PWR_ON_AC=1
WIFI_PWR_ON_BAT=5
WOL_DISABLE=Y
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_AC=0
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_BAT=1
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_CONTROLLER=Y
BAY_POWEROFF_ON_BAT=0
BAY_DEVICE="sr0"
RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC=on
RUNTIME_PM_ON_BAT=auto
RUNTIME_PM_ALL=1
RUNTIME_PM_DRIVER_BLACKLIST="radeon nouveau"
USB_AUTOSUSPEND=1
USB_BLACKLIST_WWAN=1
RESTORE_DEVICE_STATE_ON_STARTUP=0

+++ System Info
System         = Acer V1.21 Aspire 5750G
BIOS           = V1.21
Release        = Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Kernel         = 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64
/proc/cmdline  = BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic root=UUID=04c737ec-aebc-444a-b514-bbc68ae54e7d ro quiet splash
Init system    = systemd

+++ System Status
TLP power save = enabled
power source   = AC

+++ Processor
CPU Model      = Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GHz

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2900000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2900000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2900000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2900000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2900000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2900000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2900000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2900000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/min_perf_pct      = 27
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct      = 100
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo          = 0

x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu0                            = performance
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu1                            = performance
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu2                            = performance
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu3                            = performance
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu4                            = performance
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu5                            = performance
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu6                            = performance
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu7                            = performance

/proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog                          = 0

+++ Undervolting
PHC kernel not available.

+++ Temperatures
CPU temp               =    64 [°C]
Fan speed              = (not available)

+++ File System
/proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode               =     0
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs =  1500
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_expire_centisecs    =  1500
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio               =    20
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio    =    10
/proc/sys/fs/xfs/age_buffer_centisecs  = (not available)
/proc/sys/fs/xfs/xfssyncd_centisecs    = (not available)
/proc/sys/fs/xfs/xfsbufd_centisecs     = (not available)

+++ Storage Devices
/dev/sda:
          Model     = WDC WD5000BPVT-22HXZT1
          Firmware  = 01.01A01
          APM Level = 254
          Status    = active/idle
          Scheduler = deadline

```
    SMART info:
        4 Start_Stop_Count          =    22175 
        5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct     =        0 
        9 Power_On_Hours            =    12031 [h]
      193 Load_Cycle_Count          =   585507 
      194 Temperature_Celsius       =       39    [°C]
```

+++ SATA Aggressive Link Power Management
/sys/class/scsi_host/host0/link_power_management_policy  = max_performance
/sys/class/scsi_host/host1/link_power_management_policy  = max_performance
/sys/class/scsi_host/host2/link_power_management_policy  = max_performance
/sys/class/scsi_host/host3/link_power_management_policy  = max_performance
/sys/class/scsi_host/host4/link_power_management_policy  = max_performance
/sys/class/scsi_host/host5/link_power_management_policy  = max_performance

+++ PCIe Active State Power Management
/sys/module/pcie_aspm/parameters/policy = default (using bios preferences)

+++ Intel Graphics
/sys/module/i915/parameters/powersave        = (not available)
/sys/module/i915/parameters/enable_rc6       =  1 (enabled)
/sys/module/i915/parameters/enable_fbc       = -1 (use per-chip default)
/sys/module/i915/parameters/lvds_downclock   = (not available)
/sys/module/i915/parameters/semaphores       = -1 (use per-chip default)

+++ Wireless
bluetooth = off (software)
wifi      = on
wwan      = none (no device)

wlan0(ath9k)        : connected, power management = off

+++ Audio
/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save            = 0
/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save_controller = N

+++ Runtime Power Management
device classes   = all
device blacklist = (not configured)
driver blacklist = radeon nouveau

/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:00.0/power/control = on   (0x060000, Host bridge, no driver)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:01.0/power/control = on   (0x060400, PCI bridge, pcieport)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.0/power/control = on   (0x030000, VGA compatible controller, i915)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:16.0/power/control = on   (0x078000, Communication controller, mei_me)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1a.0/power/control = on   (0x0c0320, USB controller, ehci-pci)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1b.0/power/control = on   (0x040300, Audio device, snd_hda_intel)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.0/power/control = on   (0x060400, PCI bridge, pcieport)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.1/power/control = on   (0x060400, PCI bridge, pcieport)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.3/power/control = on   (0x060400, PCI bridge, pcieport)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1d.0/power/control = on   (0x0c0320, USB controller, ehci-pci)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.0/power/control = on   (0x060100, ISA bridge, lpc_ich)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.2/power/control = on   (0x010601, SATA controller, ahci)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.3/power/control = on   (0x0c0500, SMBus, no driver)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/power/control = on   (0x030000, VGA compatible controller, no driver)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:02:00.0/power/control = on   (0x020000, Ethernet controller, tg3)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:02:00.1/power/control = on   (0x080501, SD Host controller, sdhci-pci)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:02:00.2/power/control = on   (0x088000, System peripheral, no driver)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:02:00.3/power/control = on   (0x088000, System peripheral, no driver)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:03:00.0/power/control = on   (0x028000, Network controller, ath9k)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:05:00.0/power/control = on   (0x0c0330, USB controller, xhci_hcd)

+++ USB
autosuspend        = enabled
device whitelist   = (not configured)
device blacklist   = (not configured)
wwan blacklist     = enabled

Bus 002 Device 004 ID 041e:323d control = on,   autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Creative Technology, Ltd  (snd-usb-audio, usbhid)
Bus 002 Device 003 ID 046d:c52b control = on,   autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver (usbhid)
Bus 002 Device 002 ID 8087:0024 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub (hub)
Bus 002 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0002 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub (hub)
Bus 004 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0003 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub (hub)
Bus 003 Device 002 ID 046d:c52b control = on,   autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver (usbhid)
Bus 003 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0002 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub (hub)
Bus 001 Device 003 ID 064e:c218 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Suyin Corp.  (uvcvideo)
Bus 001 Device 002 ID 8087:0024 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub (hub)
Bus 001 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0002 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub (hub)

+++ Battery Status
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/manufacturer                   = SANYO 
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/model_name                     = Li_Ion_4000mA 
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/cycle_count                    = (not supported)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full_design             =   4400 [mAh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full                    =    496 [mAh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_now                     =    496 [mAh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/current_now                    =      0 [mA]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status                         = Full

how can i add code without putting spaces or a sign in front of every line?

Comment: Use http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and share the link only.

Answer (score 0):

Using TLP solved my problem.. Still only 3h of battery but that's fine :-)
http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/improve-power-usage-battery-life-in.html

Comment: Ok it didn't solve anything.. it said 3h for a few minutes. Now its down to 18minutes..

Comment: Troubleshooting ideas: Boot to a Live USB and see how long it lasts, use an older version.  Can you boot to Windows? If so, try it again to see how long it lasts.  Check your power settings to see if HDD powers down.  Have your battery tested to see if it is providing full power.

Comment: Please attach the output of `sudo tlp-stat` to your post.

Comment: Your battery is worn down to 10% capacity e.g. charge_full_design=4400 mAh vs. charge_full=496 mAh. Won't last 4h in Windows nor 3h on Linux. I suggest you replace the battery.

Comment: I read that too. But i can't believe that the capacity dropped down to 10% right in the moment i installed Ubuntu..  Are you sure it's not a softwareproblem?

Answer (score 0):

I find it is paramount to have intel_pstate in passive mode, via this kernel parameter:

Add to `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_pstate=passive"
```

Run `update-grub`

Reboot.

With this, an idle machine will result in lowest clock freq scaling.